# How to use function of one class from another class in java when running a selenium project

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Here i have built 2 classes , i want to use function "User_mgmt_A" in class 'Testjava'.
My 1st class :-
public class **testjava** extends User_mgmt {

```
        void valid_login() 
        {
            
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/neha.sharma/Downloads/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.get("http://192.168.127.54:8080/TNSRDH/login");
            BufferedReader br1= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String user="test4pds";
            System.out.print("Enter the username for the Tamil Nadu project");
            try {
                user=br1.readLine();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys(user);
            BufferedReader br2= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String pwd = "Pass@1234";
            System.out.println("Enter the password for Tamil Nadu project");
            try {
                pwd=br2.readLine();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            driver.findElement(By.id("txtPassword")).sendKeys(pwd);
           driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            Select department=new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("department")));
            department.selectByIndex(3);
            driver.findElement(By.id("btn")).click();
    
        public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException 
        {
    testjava login= new testjava();
    User_mgmt mgmt=new User_mgmt();
    login.valid_login();
    mgmt.User_mgmt_A();
    }
    
    ---------------------------------------------------------
My 2nd class:-
    public class User_mgmt {
        void User_mgmt_A() throws IOException
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/neha.sharma/Downloads/chromedriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            /*driver.get("http://192.168.127.54:8080/TNSRDH/login");
            driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("Test4pds");
            driver.findElement(By.id("txtPassword")).sendKeys("Pass@1234");
            Select department=new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("department")));
            department.selectByIndex(3);
            driver.findElement(By.id("btn")).click(); */
             WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 4000);
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated((By.id("id"))));
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'User Management')]")).click(); //selecting user management icon
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'showUserSubModule?submodule=userCreation')]")).click(); // selecting 'User creation' link
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[(@src='images/adduser.png')]")).click(); // selecting 'Add user' link
            
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='userform']/div[4]/div[2]/div/button")).click(); // selecting department in Add user form
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='userform']/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[2]/label/input")).click(); // selecting 'CMUPT' Department
            driver.findElement(By.id("firstName")).sendKeys("ArunTester");
            driver.findElement(By.id("middleName")).sendKeys("Srinivas");
            driver.findElement(By.id("lastName")).sendKeys("B");
            driver.findElement(By.id("loginName")).sendKeys("ArunTester12");
           /* List RadioBtn= (List) driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-4']"));
            BufferedReader Radio= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String radioM="Male";
            radioM=Radio.readLine();
            if (radioM.equals(Radio))
            {
                driver.findElement(By.id("sex1")).click();
            }
            
            driver.findElement(By.id("sex")).click();
            
             */      
            
        }
    
        private WebElement RadioBtn(int i) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
    
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException 
    {
        System.exit(0);
    
    }
    }
```

Please let me know how can a function be called in different class . I tried using 'Extend' keyword but it didn't worked.

Comment: Go through this link http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html  , which will give you the basics of Eclipse- Code Debugging

Answer (score 0):

You might want to learn the basics of Object-Oriented Programming (OOP) first.
As far as I understand you, you want to extend your class "testjava" with the class "User_mgmt" in order to use the method User_mgmt_A() in "testjava".

First things first:

For the love of god read the [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf)!

The class-names and method-names that you are using are not understandable.

Next, as I mentioned before, catch up on OOP.

If your "User_mgmt" really should be the base class of "testjava" then refer to the following sample code to make it work in your own codebase:

File: Pet.java

```
package de.myproject.samples;
class Pet{
 private String name;
 protected String getName(String name){return this.name;}
 public Pet(String name){
   this.name=name;
 }
}
```

File: Dog.java

```
package de.myproject.samples;
class Dog extends Pet{
 public Dog(String name){
  super(name);
  System.out.println("The dogs name is "+this.getName());
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank You for your comments !!

Answer (score 0):

In java you call it as `methods` and not functions and you can access it by creating object of one class in another and call it by using that object.